# How much will I be saving off of interests if I fully pay my mortgage earlier?

Tags: mortgage, interest-rate, philippines

I purchased a vacant lot and opted to pay for it in installment for 60 months at an annual fixed rate.

This formula was used to calculate my monthly fee: `M = P[i(1+i)^n / ((1+i)^n-1)]`

I am currently in my 24/60 months of payment and I recently came up with quite a reasonable amount of money so I was thinking of paying it in full. Excuse my ignorance, but is it correct to assume that they will use the formula above and just change the `n` to 24? Which means my new total balance will be `24M-X` where X is the amount of money I have paid them so far?

Essentially what I'm getting at is this, my original amortization table is calculated for 60 months of payment. Since I want to have it fully paid by the 24th month, I assume the initial amortization table will be moot and that a new one will be made for me with new calculations as if I originally decided for a 24-month loan ultimately giving me a considerably lower interest overall?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you pay it in full, how could your balance be anything other than 0?  Whatever the interest rate is, any rate times 0 should be 0.

Comment: Make sure there are no pre-payment or early payoff penalties.  Most banks these days do not seem to do that any more, but there might still be a few banks whose mortgages penalize you for doing early payoffs or payments, since they lose out on interest by you doing so.

Comment: Might be badly worded, I want to figure out how much I need to pay in order to make the balance = 0 since I will have paid it all in under 25 months and not 60 months as originally calculated.

Comment: Oh, then you should update the summary of the question.  To know the amount to pay off now, your bank should be able to provide that.  Every bank I have borrowed from has had a web site I can log into where I can view a "payoff amount", which is the current balance plus any accrued interest.  Essentially, it executes the above formula and tells you the number.  If your bank doesn't offer than, give them a call.  They ought to be able to tell you.

Comment: Worst case, you can pay the remaining balance, which will leave only accrued interest, which at that point, will probably be a very small amount.  Then just pay that amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to get a reasonable estimate of what you still owe, and then the way to get the exact value.

When the loan started they should have given you amortization table that laid out each payment including the principal, interest and balance for each payment. If there are any other fees included in the payment those also should have been detailed.

Determine how may payments you have maid: did you make the first payment on day one, or the start of the next month? Was the last payment the 24th, or the next one? The table will then tell you what you owe after your most recent payment.

To get the exact value call the lender. The amount grows  between payment due to the interest that is accumulating. They will need to know when the payment will arrive so they can give you the correct value.

To calculate how much you will save do the following calculation:

payment = monthly payment for principal and interest
paymentsmade =Number of payments made = 24
paymentsremaining = Number of payments remaining = 60 - paymentsmade = 60-24 = 36
instantpayoff = number from loan company

savings = (payment * paymentsremaining ) - instantpayoff

Comment: I did have an amortization table however that is calculated with the assumption that I was going to pay off the whole amount in 60 months. Since longer loan time means bigger interest, I was wondering if I can save a lot on interest by cutting the loan time in more than half.

Comment: I realize it now that whatever amortization table I start with still applies even if I decide to pay off entire the balance on that month. Thanks.